# Running a Batch file in C# Form

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there was any way for me to put my .BAT file into my C# Form like here :https://prnt.sc/s1ne88

Is there any way that i can run the BAT from inside the Form

Other Terms : I only want to download the Exe and have the BAT inside the C# form and it run from inside

Comment: you can execute a batch file (or any other executable) from a C# program, yes. Pretty sure you can find examples on google already.

Comment: You can include the file in your C# program using the .NET embedded resoruce managers. But you cannot run a batch file from memory, which you would have to do, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6243053/653473). You could embed the batch file as text, and then execute it in some other way, for example, by writing it to a temporary file first.

Comment: you can change the Copy to Output Directory property for the .bat file to be in the same folder as the executable

Answer (score 3):

you can create the bat file from your application using StreamWriter and then run it:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file.bat");
sw.WriteLine("ping 8.8.8.8");
sw.Dispose();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("file.bat");
```

**OR**

you can run the bat commands directly from your application: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)

```
string cmd = "/k ipconfig";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", cmd);
```